# Run Python script multiple times with different inputs

Tags: python, loops, variables

I am new to programming.

My script does the following:

1. Converts single Excel sheet into single CSV file
2. Opens that CSV file and adds new column with number and saves it

```py
import pandas as pd

data_xls = pd.read_excel('excel_file.xlsx', ' tab_name ', index_col=None)
data_xls.to_csv('tab_name.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
data_csv = pd.read_csv('tab_name.csv')
data_csv.insert(0, 'new_column_header', range(1, 1 + len(df)))
data_csv.to_csv('tab_name.csv', index=False )
```

My challenge:

Excel document consists of multiple sheets (tabs) let's say: "tab1, tab2, tab3".

I need guidance how to run the same script in a loop over multiple tabs (i.e. list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
dict_dfs = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet_name=None)
```

This will return you an OrderedDict whose keys will be the sheet names and values will be dataframes.

All you need is to loop over and do your manipulations and then save the individual dataframes as csv.

```
for k in dict_dfs:
    # your processing here
    dict_dfs[k].to_csv("custom_filename_for_each_dataframe.csv")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! that one works as well! you are amazing guys!

Comment: Wonderful, i am happy. Please accept as the final answer :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to hard-code your tab names in a list and loop over them.

```
for tab in ["tab1", "tab2", "tab3"]:
    data_xls = pd.read_excel('excel_file.xlsx', tab, index_col=None)
    data_xls.to_csv(tab + '.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
    data_csv = pd.read_csv(tab + '.csv')
    data_csv.insert(0, 'new_column_header', range(1, 1 + len(df)))
    data_csv.to_csv(tab + '.csv', index=False )
```

Comment: That is what I need. Thanks for rapid help!